# Generic table editor/viewer

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I am attempting to create a generic table viewer/editor using MVC 6, ASP.Net 5 and Entity Framework 7. I have done this before in PHP with a MySQL backend, so I'm fine for visualising most things, the hard part is doing the same in c#/EF7.

I have asked a question related to this here - [Get DbSet from type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34259504/get-dbset-from-type) - and this is my current attempt at solving this problem.

This question is more of a general question - Is it possible to create a table viewer/editor that is capable of performing the same functions as, for example, a http://datatables.net/ datatable with Search/Filter/Pagination support. (I have implemented an identical type of control in PHP/JS with no issues at all)

From what I can tell, you have to use a lot of reflection in C# to achieve anything near this, and as such, was wondering if someone could possibly either point me in the right direction to an existing solution or a new solution for this. Or, alternatively, if this is not really possible - besides going through and writing a million switch statements to ensure that the correct `DbSet` and/or `DbContext` is selected.

Comment: @Micky I'm currently using `DbContext`s and `DbSet`s and have not found any way in which one can access the properties of a dynamic `DbSet` and perform LINQ queries on it. Should I be looking at manually writing the SQL?

Comment: @Micky, as to the _"million switch statements"_, that was in reference to the fact that I can't access the individual properties of the object because it is in its generic form.

Comment: Ah I see. Yes agreed. Generally the point of using something like EF or nHibernate was for type-safety to known entity types.  Since you will be dynamic, I agree that SQL might be the way to go. Or at least maybe ADO.NET?

Comment: @Micky, ok, looks like that's what I'll have to do, unless someone has a way around EF that can do it. :)

Comment: Maybe look at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34259504/get-dbset-from-type/71749072#71749072